# Python: Different Files for Different Tasks?

Tags: python

I'm working on an app that has several buttons (10+) on the home screen that take the user to different pages with different functions, like home screen on Android or iOS where apps are located. The problem is, if all the different functions accessed from the home screen were to be put into one file, it would end up being over 10,000 lines in a single `.py`, which I've read is not good practice and can slow down the process.

How would one make it so that when the user presses a button for a task on the home screen, it accesses the code from a different `.py` without opening up a new window?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is "opening up a new window"?

Comment: Use `import` from another module?

Comment: It would be like creating a new instance of the application running at the same time.

Comment: I couldn't find a very good guide on how to use ```import``` with a file that you've created and not a module or library. Do you have any advice?

Comment: See [Python Application Layouts: A Reference](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/).